# What component can be used to display a large amount of information?

Tags: angular, angular-material

What can be done if  need to use  `select` component when adding or update a record? But this component cannot be used, since a large amount of information should be displayed, and because of this there will be a slow data rate. Using pagination in a component `select` will look ugly. If that I use `Angular Material`.

Comment: Unable to understand the question!

Comment: What do you mean by `select` component? Can you add sample code or bit more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

large amount of information means that you have vertical or horizontal scroll ?

if so, you can use virtual scroll, which will help your performance.

you can use https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable.

they have a demo with 100k rows. we use it in our company  use it. high quality package.

Comment: That is, assuming there will be 1000+ entries, will it work well?